# Handling non created object in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, singleton

I have created a class using the singleton design pattern. The main objective of the class is to create an email id only when the email is valid. If the email is not valid it will not create an object. Users can get their email with the help of the `attr_reader`. Here is my implementation.

```rb
class Email
  attr_accessor :email
  private_class_method :new

  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
  end

  def email_validate?
    if is_valid?
      puts "Email successfully created!"
      return true
    else
      puts "Can not be created. Not a valid email!"
      return false
    end
  end

  def self.create(email)
    self.new(email) if self.new(email).email_validate?
  end

  private

  def is_valid?
    @email =~ /^[a-zA-Z]*(\w+\.?)*\w[@]\w+[.][a-z]{1,4}$/
  end
end

my_email = Email.create("some.mail.id@domain.com")
puts my_email.email
```

Now the problem with this implementation is, if the email is not valid then no object of `Email` is created. Hence

```rb
bad_email = Email.create("!a..bad..mail@.com")
bad_email.email #error -> breaks the code.
```

Rather i want code to output like something this

```rb
bad_email = Email.create("!a..bad..mail@.com")
bad_email.email #output -> Error: No email is created.
```

So is the possibility to use something like `begin`, `raise`, and `resue` inside the class to achieve this? Or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen instead? Should an instance of Email be created, but with a blank email? Or should the instance have a dedicated `success?` method or a `errors` method? Or do you simple want to raise an exception with a useful message?

Comment: Yes, I want it to print some error message. I have updated the question. You can refer that.

Comment: The `email_validate?` function is really out of place here. That's a display concern, and should be handled by the caller. What you might want is a `validation_message` method that instead returns the text that *could* be displayed. Forcing a `puts` is forcing a particular use case.

Comment: Your `create` method creates twice as well, which is completely unnecessary. Consider: `created = self.new(email)` and then `created.is_valid? and created` which will return the newly created instance if and only if it's valid. As you've observed here, blocking creation leads to tricky error handling down the line, so maybe you should just create it regardless, and shift validation to a separate concern.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over complicating it or maybe misusing an `Email` class a bit. Always keep it as simple as you need:

```rb
class Email
  attr_accessor :id, :email
  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
  end

  def valid?
    /^[a-zA-Z]*(\w+\.?)*\w[@]\w+[.][a-z]{1,4}$/.match? email
  end

  def save
    return unless valid?
    @id = 1  # saved
  end
end
```

```rb
>> email = Email.new("an@email.com")
=> #<Email:0x00007f1358d68608 @email="an@email.com">
>> email.valid?
=> true
>> email.save
=> 1
>> email
=> #<Email:0x00007f1358d68608 @email="an@email.com", @id=1>
```

```rb
>> email = Email.new("not@an@email.com")
=> #<Email:0x00007f1358b57210 @email="not@an@email.com">
>> email.valid?
=> false
>> email.save
=> nil
```

---

If you don't keep it simple there is no end in what you can do. For an email you can just add a method to validate it. If validation becomes necessary somewhere else, you can make a class for it, to separate so called concerns. If you want to keep chaining methods `NullObject` pattern can be used as `InvalidEmail`. Add `build` method to just handle the object creation paperwork, I think, this would be a *factory method* in this case:

```rb
class Email
  def self.build str
    if Validator.validate str
      new str
    else
      InvalidEmail.new str
    end
  end

  def self.create str
    build(str).save
  end

  attr_accessor :id, :email
  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      Persistor.save(self)
    else
      InvalidEmail.new email
    end
  end

  def valid?
    Validator.validate(email)
  end

  class Validator
    def self.validate str
      /^[a-zA-Z]*(\w+\.?)*\w[@]\w+[.][a-z]{1,4}$/.match? str
    end
  end

  class Persistor
    def self.save email
      puts "email saved"
      email.id = 1
      email
    end
  end
  
  class ::InvalidEmail < Email
    def save
      self
    end

    def valid?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
>> str = "invalid.email"
=> "invalid.email"
>> Email::Validator.validate(str)
=> false
>> Email.build(str)
=> #<InvalidEmail:0x00007fc8303894d8 @email="invalid.email">
>> Email.create(str)
=> #<InvalidEmail:0x00007fc8264628c8 @email="invalid.email">
>> Email.new(str).valid?
=> false
>> Email.new(str).save
=> #<InvalidEmail:0x00007fc8259ae800 @email="invalid.email">

>> Email.create("valid@email.com")
email saved
=> #<Email:0x00007fc8303bc1f8 @email="valid@email.com", @id=1>
```

You can change behavior as needed. If you need to log a message instead:

```rb
class InvalidEmail < Email
  def save
    self
  end

  def valid?
    false
  end

  def email
    puts "Error: No email is created."
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Email.create("email").email
Error: No email is created.
=> nil
```

Comment: But with I second approach. I will not get the desired behavior. 
`my_email = Email.create("bad.email") my_email.email # bad.email`

Comment: @S_coderX451 see update. you can override email method, with specific behavior for invalid emails.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. `def email
    return @email if @email
    puts "Error. No email is created"
  end` and `def self.create(email)
    created = self.new(email)
    return created if created.email_validation?
    return self.new(nil)
  end`. This works fine.